# I want to pass my input values from Form to handleSubmit ()

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to pass my input values from form to handleSubmit () currently I am passing `e.target.value` and getting an error cannot property 'value' of undefined.

following is the form code block from where I want to get the values

```
 <Input
      label="Write a message..."
      name="message"
      type="text"
    />
```

and the following is the code block from where I am trying to access the value under

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
       this.props.sendNewMessage(e.target.value);
      }
```

Full code for reference :

```
import React from 'react';
import SubMenu from './SubMenu';
import MessageForm from './form/MessageForm';
import { sendNewMessage } from '../../actions/messages.actions'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';


class Messages extends React.PureComponent {
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
       this.props.sendNewMessage(e.target.value);
      }

    render() {
        return (
            <section className="page-notifications"> 
                <SubMenu/>
                <MessageForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
            </section>
        )
    }
}
    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
      return {
        sendNewMessage: (msg) => dispatch(sendNewMessage(msg)),
      }
    }

export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(Messages)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't how you should handle form submissions. Your `messageForm` should update your state using an `onChange` handler. Then `handleSubmit` should `preventDefault()` and dispatch your `sendNewMessage` action using the value(s) from state that have already been set.

The [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) are very helpful on this.

Comment: so I just need to pass "value" to handle submit ... well it worked

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your method for getting value from child component

```
constructer(props){
super(props);
   this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
```

Now you shouldn't get undefined error

Answer (score 0):

So @Will suggested me to add values to my handleSubmit(), it solved my problem thank you all.
 following is code snippet where I made changes :

```
handleSubmit = (value) => {
      this.props.sendNewMessage(value);
      console.log(value)
    }
```